# Removing Characters in Python Based On Neighboring Characters

Tags: python, string, parsing

I have a str importing from an API, which, when there are special characters `!@#$%^&*()`, it always is preceded by a `\`. I would like to parse the strings to remove the `\`, but only when superseded by `!@#$%^&*()`, as it is possible for these strs to contain `\` natively.

I have been using the `replace()` class, but this removes all `\`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lookahead regex pattern to ensure that a matching backslash is followed by one of the special characters:

```
import re
string = r'/foo\ \@ bar\!'
string = re.sub(r'\\(?=[!@#$%^&*()])', '', string)
print(string)
```

This outputs:

```
/foo\ @ bar!
```